# Mongo aggregate $group by each day?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, group-by, aggregation

I have a collection of history, and want to create the exports data base on that collection

```
[{
_id: "...",
value: 10,
at: ISODate("2021-24-06T00:01:02.023")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 13,
at: ISODate("2021-24-06T00:04:11.211")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 12,
at: ISODate("2021-24-06T09:11:31.182")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-07T01:33:31.723")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-15T09:32:44.983")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-16T10:43:22.083")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-16T14:43:22.083")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-17T04:25:12.021")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-18T20:13:22.083")
}, {
_id: ...,
value: 40,
at: ISODate("2021-24-19T18:41:22.083")
}]
```

I have to expose 3 options group by: hours, day, week

I'm trying use $group to calculate mix/max or avg of value in a day but don't know how to $group them to each hour/day/weeks data

Can I group by $cond ?
Because it very flexible for all the case.

Example: Group by hours, first moment = 2021-24-06T00:00:00.000
Expect:

```
[{
  at: ISODate("2021-24-06T00:00:00.000"),
  max: 13,
  min: 10,
  avg: 21.5
}, {
  at: ISODate("2021-24-06T01:00:00.000"),
}, ..., {
  at: ISODate("2021-24-06T09:00:00.000"),
  max: 12,
  min: 12,
  avg: 12
}]
```

Group By = day

Expect:

```
[{
  at: ISODate("2021-24-06T00:00:00.000"),
  max: 13,
  min: 10,
  avg: 11.7
}, {
  at: ISODate("2021-24-07T00:00:00.000"),
  max: 40,
  min 40,
  avg: 40,
}]
```

It is my idea. Create the first moments of each group, compare `at` with first moment and last moment of group.

Ex:  group by day, first moment of first group is at: `ISODate("2021-24-06T00:00:00.000")` -> last moment = `ISODate("2021-24-06T23:59:59.999")` -> Group all record belong to this group

second group: `ISODate("2021-24-06T00:00:00.000")` + 1day = `ISODate("2021-24-07T00:00:00.000")` -> last moment = `ISODate("2021-24-07T23:59:59.999")` -> Group all record belong to this group

But how to implement that

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators Hope this helps!

Comment: Use $bucket, precalculate the ranges you want to aggregate by and pass them in explicitly.

Comment: @D.SM Oh it seems a good suggestion. I will try it and report back in next comment

Comment: @D.SM Work well, many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$dateToString` in the Group By `$group` clause to group your data based on `Day` & `Hour`. You can use `$week` in the Group By `$group` clause to group your data based on `Week`.

***Please take a look at the below code:***

**Sample Data**
[image: Sample Data]

**Group By Week**

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $week: '$at' },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

[image: Group By Week]

**Group By Day**

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$at" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

[image: Group By Day]

**Group By Hour**

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H", date: "$at" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

[image: Group By Hour]

[See more details about the `$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-day-of-the-year)

[See more details about the `$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

[See more details about the `$week`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/)

**Update using TimeZone in the query**

You can use `timezone` in the `$dateToString` expression. Please check the below examples:

[image: Time Zone added in the group by]

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$at", timezone: "-05:00" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])

db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$at", timezone: "+07:00" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

You will find more about the expression in the link below including the `timezone`.

[MongoDB $dateToString](https://database.guide/mongodb-datetostring/)

**`timezone` added in the hour example:**

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H", date: "$at", timezone: "+00:30" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

**`timezone` added in the week example:**

```
db.collData.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
       _id : { $week: { date: '$at', timezone: "-05:00" } },
       averageValue: { $avg: "$value" },
       count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort : { averageValue: -1 }
  }
])
```

Comment: I need to group data by days and odd hours, because the timeZone is not UTC +0.
Ex: Group by day of 2022-12-16 of timeZone +7 => I have to get data from 2022-12-15T14:00:00 to 2022-12-16T13:59:59 of UtC +0. This why I cannot use $group and $dateToString, The timeZone could be is UTC +0.5 so the minimum unit is minute

Comment: @VũAnhDũng, please check the updated part of the answer. The expression `$dateToString` allows `timezone`.

Comment: how about week ? It also support timezone ? and hours I can group even timeZone is +0.5. Have to group from 0:30 -> 1:30, 1:30 -> 2:30 ...

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding the `timezone` in the hour and the week example.

Comment: I have done by use $bucket and have tried your solution use $group. The result is same, it's very nice. I will compare the performance 2 ways and choose the better performance. Many thanks @csharpbd

Comment: Hey man, my example documents above is very simple. It's the real structure of document.

{
  at: Date,
  history: [{
    type: { type: String, enum: ["temp", "moisture"]},
    value: Number,
  }]
}

History is a nested array and my goal is avg of temps, moist group by hours/days/weeks. I pushed 2 pipe to aggregate is { $unwind: "$history" } and { "type": "temp" } to calculate only temp or only moisture. If I don't filter, it calculate all of history.value both temp and hum, and it's wrong. So I have to separate to 2 query, 1 for temp, 1 for moisture. Can I combine them

Comment: Could you please add some example JSON?

Comment: Sure, here is it: https://mongoplayground.net/p/STRdgMNqnmG

Comment: My expect is the same question of this post, but have calculate for each type.
Sample result: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ddyugq757G4

Comment: ok, thanks for the sample data. I will try to make a query for your expected result.

Comment: I have also a question in this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68127955/mongo-how-to-group-by-week-but-return-start-date-and-end-date-of-each-week-ins

Please take a look

Comment: @VũAnhDũng, could you please take a look at the link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/06w4SwC4Udr

Comment: Thanks @csharpbd. I will try it

Comment: It's better if we can combine temp. moist to one object. Look like: { tempMax: 1, moistMax: 1. tempMin: 0, moistMin: 1 } instead of separate to another object and identified by sensorType

Comment: Can we still return { tempMax: null } of an hour if in that hour have not any data ?

Comment: I will look into it.

Comment: @VũAnhDũng, I've worked and found a way to achieve the desired output. But there is something that you have to follow. I added some comments in the query. Please take a look at the comments carefully. Please check the below link for the query.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tPscyu3WpLD