# Mongo: How to group by $week but return start date and end date of each week instead?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I am using $group by $week. It's returning the #week in the year, but I want the start date, end date of each week instead of

Sample:

Current result:

```
[{
    "_id" : 20,
    "averageValue" : null
},
{
    "_id" : 21,
    "averageValue" : 28.1875
}]
```

Expect:

```
[{
    "_id" : [{ start: "2021-01-01", "end": "2021-01-07" }],
    "averageValue" : null
},
{
    "_id" : [{ start: "2021-01-08", "end": "2021-01-14" }],
    "averageValue" : 28.1875
}]
```

Comment: Can you pass sample source data?

Comment: i don't think it's possible to get start and end date from week in mongodb, you can do it in your client-side language.

Comment: @turivishal yes, if mongo is not supported that feature, I have to do it in code, but there is hard to compare #week with time to push data correctly. If in database, don't have data of some weeks, mongo still the data of missing week ?
Ex: Week #3 don't have any data, mongo still return [{ _id: 1 }, { _id: 2 }, { _id: 3 }, { _id: 4 }] or return on week #1, #2, #4

Comment: mongodb will not return missing week document as well. what language you are using?

Comment: @turivishal I'm using nodejs

Comment: @hhharsha36 Like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/uaIajJ5AF5g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is doable, makes code less readable and more complex.

I will rewrite the `$group` stage to include `year` along with `weeks` and add the `$project` stage to format the data as per requirement.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "week": {
          "$week": {"$subtract": ["$at", 25200000]}  // <-- Changes timezone to -07:00
        },
        "year": {
          "$year": {"$subtract": ["$at", 25200000]}  // <-- Changes timezone to -07:00
        },
      },
      // <-- Add keys to be added in group along with its logics
      "averageValue": {
        "$avg": "$readings.level_1"
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": {
        "startDate": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
              }
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          },
        },
        "endDate": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "date": {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$dateFromParts": {
                    "isoWeekYear": "$_id.year",
                    "isoWeek": "$_id.week"
                  }
                },
                518400000,
              ],
            },
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
          },
        },
      },
      // <-- Add remaining keys to be projected
      "averageValue": 1,
    },
  },
])
```

Let me know if you need an explanation of each stage and operator used and why I used it.

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3XSngowtPZc)

Comment: Can you explain why we need $year ?

Comment: We won't need the year reference if all the dates in the `at` field are in the same year. But, there will be a conflict if the years are different as the group by weeks will get mixed with another year's records.

Comment: will it still working if I push timezone to: { _id: { week: { $week: { date: '$at', timezone: '+07:00' }}}}

Comment: Yes, it will. But you have to change the timezone wherever date-related Operators are used.

Comment: My destination is get all data (in UTC) based on location timezone. it mean if in my location, timezone = +7 => I have to get data from yesterday  17:00 UTC but still _id.start and _id.end as location timezone.

Comment: Oh, we have a problem. Today is friday, 2021-06-25 but the last week, mongo returns:
"time": {
       "start": "2021-06-21",
       "end": "2021-06-27"
},

We added over the current time, it's time in future because 06-27 is sunday

Comment: @VũAnhDũng I have updated the answer with the inclusion of timezone. See if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution to your question. In this solution, I've used a (minimum date) `date` value to find the `week start` and `week end`. Please take a look at the code below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$history"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "at": {
          $week: {
            date: "$at",
            timezone: "-05:00"
          }
        },
        "type": "$history.type"
      },
      minDate: {
        $min: "$at",
        
      },
      averageValue: {
        $avg: "$history.value",
        
      },
      minimumValue: {
        $min: "$history.value",
        
      },
      maximumValue: {
        $max: "$history.value",
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$_id.at",
      "type": "$_id.type",
      "averageValue": "$averageValue",
      "minimumValue": "$minimumValue",
      "maximumValue": "$maximumValue",
      "weekStart": {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            // convert date
            $subtract: [
              "$minDate",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        $isoDayOfWeek: "$minDate"
                      },
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  86400000
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "weekEnd": {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: {
            // convert date
            $subtract: [
              "$minDate",
              {
                $multiply: [
                  {
                    $subtract: [
                      {
                        $isoDayOfWeek: "$minDate"
                      },
                      7
                    ]
                  },
                  86400000
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playround example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kLuNPhhaomg)